# How we can upgrad with upgrader package for latest version '1.0.0' in flutter build gradle

Tags: android, flutter, dart

in my case

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "blblblb"
   
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionName "1.0"
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do?